# How to push new or updated files from Azure Data lake to File folder using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, file, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am able to push data using copy tool from Azure data lake to local file folders using Azure Data Factory.

But I just want to push only updated or new files from Azure data lake to File Folder (I mean only delta pull) .

I tried with parameter option but not able to give parameters. Can anyone of you suggest how to achieve this .

Comment: I think you can use event trigger. But there seems to be no trigger for file update.

Comment: Blob event trigger would be useful here. It's a bit of a misnomer, but the BlobCreated trigger fires when either a new blob is inserted or replaced (updated).

Comment: Joel Cochran , source is not a Blob its from Azure Data Lake Gen 1

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to push only updated or new files from Azure data lake to
>   File Folder (I mean only delta pull) .

Based on your description, you want to implement incremental load in ADLS source.Actually, this is implemented with LastModifiedDate property of files.

[image]

You could execute the pipeline in the schedule so that you could load the new files regularly.More details, please refer to below links:

1.https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/incrementally-copy-new-files-by-lastmodifieddate-with-azure-data-factory/

2.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview#loading-new-and-changed-files-only-by-using-lastmodifieddate

Comment: Thanks Jay for this , I have tried this option of Filter by last modified start time and End time but although pipeline is successful i am not able to see any file transmission from source to target. can you through some knowledge on parameters. Is there anything to do with parameters and how we can use this.

Comment: It's ok. So you mean you already set the filter condition but no data was pulled out. Have you checked the exact modified date time of your files?

Comment: Yes Jay gong i have already used the filter condition but its of no luck . Does we need to pass parameters for this ?

Comment: @565 Well, i don't think parameter is necessary. How about testing with some test files first? For example,create multiple files with some specific date time then load them with modified time?

Comment: I have followed similar steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-lastmodified-copy-data-tool but my source is Azure Data Lake , I have used the same property Incremental Load : Last modified date . Although pipeline is working fine but it is acting like a full pull incremental load is not working . Is it because the Incremental Load : Last modified date will only work for different dates does it wont apply if new files are added in same day.